Statics problem from classical mechanics
I was solving David Morin's book on classical mechanics.


In the solution for the second part of the "a" part of the question, why is the normal force defined as $Ndθ$ and not just $N$? Is that just to solve the problem or is there an actual reason?

$N$ is the tension. Small segments around angle $\theta$ on the surface will have $2$ forces acting on them with magnitutde $N$ and making angles $d\theta/2$. Then their sum will be radial with magnitude $2Nsin(d\theta/2) = Nd\theta$

@MahammadYusifov thanks

If we were just solving part (a) we would say that $N$ is constant and leave it outside of the integral. However, the integral is presumably being set up for part (b) in which $N$ will depend on $\theta$, so the normal force on a small arc of length $d \theta$ at an angle $\theta$ from the vertical will be $N(\theta) d \theta$.
